# AR Camera Black Screen in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

Unity 2019.4.1f1
I have built and ran the demo scene with a cube successfully before. Now, the build is only showing a black screen and the camera permission is never raised when starting the build for the first time. And the camera never shows anything. Does anyone have any ideas what might have changed?

Using Pixel XL, ARCore, ARFoundation
or while using the iOS version with iPad Pro, ARKit, ARFoundation.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.  I've tried unity versions:
2020.2.0a13
2019.4.3f1 LTS

It works with the older version of AR Foundation 3 and 2 respectively, but once I go to AR Foundation 4 is gives the same issue.

I tried adding the link.xml as suggested here (July 9 2020) but it didn't help:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-foundation-android-black-screen-on-first-launch-bug-il2cpp.671467/

I'm gonna go back to Unity 2019.4.3f1 LTS with AR Foundation 2.1.# and see if that will give me the functionality I need.

I also tried installing these apps on my phone in case it helped (no joy):
AR Core Depth Lab
AR Core Elements
Google Play Services for AR

I'd love to get v4 running for the extra features if anybody knows?

Thanks
Neil

Pixel 2
ARCore 4.0.4
AR Foundation 4.0.2
AR Subsystems 4.0.1

Comment: Go to the player settings -> XR Plugin -> XR Plugin Management and then in iOS enable the ARKit box and the ARCore box in the Android part.
This should do the trick.

Comment: why isn't this enabled upon importing the package?

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same problems. But the video link I've shared helped me.
Follow the instructions given in the video whose link is shared below:

https://youtu.be/jBRxY2KnrUs

Mostly, the problem arises because we use different versions of the packages required. In the beginning of the video there is a list of recommended package versions for different versions of Unity game engine.
Note:Don't forget to disable Multithreaded rendering under Edit | Project Settings | Player | Other Settings | Multithreaded Rendering. And change the scripting backend to IL2CPP and target architecture to ARM64.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem last night when i made ARCore project with ARCore SDK from here https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk. But for a note, i did not use AR Foundation.

When i built and run it, there was no error but the whole screen is black. Even though there was no error but i checked there were 2 warning and one of them is about Vulkan graphics being not compatible with XR. So i remove the Vulkan from **Edit > Project Settings... > PLayer > Android > Graphics API > remove the Vulkan**

And when i built and ran it again it works!